# How can I make the Kerr black hole surfaces scale well in my diagrams?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, kerr-metric

I've read that the equatorial radius of the ergosphere of a rotating black hole is the Schwarzschild radius. But in [this animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kerr.black.hole.shadow.and.horizons.gif) made in natural units by Yukterez it doesn't apply.

[image]

I then used [Yukterez equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kerr.black.hole.shadow.and.horizons.gif) in Geogebra and I observed the same thing. No surface scales accordingly. In the extremal case, the event horizon at the equator should be half the Schwarzschild radius, but it isn't.

[image: a = 0][image: a=1]

Is this a consecuence of using natural units? How could I "fix" this?

Comment: After reading a little bit more, I think maybe it is the coordinate system used. This aniamtion used cartesian and pseudospherical https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kerr-Flaechen_thumbnail.gif What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Stellar_Enginner wrote: *"In the extremal case, the event horizon at the equator should be half the Schwarzschild radius, but it isn't."*

The polar radius R<sub>p</sub>=√(x²+z²) in your a=1 image is r<sub>s</sub>/2=1, but since this is the {x,y,z} projection of the pseudospherical {r,θ,φ} coordinates the equatorial R<sub>e</sub>=√(x²+y²) is larger than r. On the equator at θ=π/2 we get R=√(r²+a²sin²θ) → R=√(r²+a²), so with a=1 we have r<sub>+</sub>=1 → R<sub>+</sub>=√2.

> Stellar_Enginner asked: *"This animation used cartesian and pseudospherical coordinates. What is the difference between them?"*

In the {r,θ,φ} coordinates where the ellipsoids have constant r the tensors and equations are simpler, but to see the ring form of the singularity you need the proper {x,y,z} projection. So do all the calculations in {r,θ,φ} and project to {x,y,z} after you're done.

> Stellar_Enginner asked: *"Is this a consequence of using natural units?"*

The units don't change the geometry, but if you use the irreducible mass ℳ instead of the mass energy M in your length scale then the equatorial horizon is always at r=2Gℳ/c². In you go with M the equatorial ergosphere is always at r=2GM/c², but the difference between spheres and ellipsoids does not come from there.

> Stellar_Enginner asked: *"How could I fix this?"*

If you want the projection of the horizons to be depicted spherical instead of elliptical just transform {r,θ,φ} to {x,y,z} as if they were regular [spherical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions) coordinates, otherwise use the proper [transformation](https://i.ibb.co/1nXs738/a.png).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, is the cartesian projection "physically correct"? If the Schwarzschild radius is 14Km for example, and in the diagram it maps to lenght 2, does it make physical sense to calculate the dimensions of the oblate event horizon, its surface area,...

Comment: For the physical distances you need the metric tensor, the cartesian projection is closer to the true distances but it isn't 100% since the BH geometry is not euclidean, while your screen is. To calculate the circumference you need the corresponding metric coefficient, for example the circumference along the equator is $\int_0^{2\pi}\surd g_{\phi\phi} \ d\phi$ and that from pole to pole and back $\int_0^{2\pi}\surd g_{\theta\theta} \ d\theta$. The cartesian projection shows the proper circumference (measured by ZAMOs) along $\theta$ (viewed edge on), but not along $\phi$ (top view) and $\rm r$